# simple CSS question

Tags: css

In the index file I have this :

```
<div id="head">
<h1>bla bla bla bla bla bla</h1>
</div>
```

And I style it like this:

```
#head{
  height : 100px;
  width : 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: #FFCC99;
}


#head h1 {
  margin-left : 20px;
  font-family : Georgia;
  font-size : 40px;
}
```

The problem is that when the screen is too small the end of the text goes under like this:

```
bla bla bla bl
a bla bla
```

and what I want to happen is just to fade awaya like :

```
bla bla bl
```

and the rest of the text just not to be shown untill the screen is resized again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this to your h1 css:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this beacuse it looks simplier and now it's just as I wanted it.

Answer (score 3):

add

```
overflow: hidden;
width: 100px; /*or whatever width you want*/
```

to your `<h1>`css statement.

It will not hide anything as you haven't told it what size width you want to hide from? Setting the width will allow you to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#head{
            height : 100px;
            width : 100%;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color: #FFCC99;
        }
        #head h1 {
            margin-left : 20px;
            font-family : Georgia;
            font-size : 40px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

<div id="head">
<h1>bla bla bla bla bla bla</h1>
</div>
```